# Dice counter error

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im making a program in python 2.7 that are going to roll dices, and then count how many times each number gets rolled. But cant seem to figure out this problem.

it  returns: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DiceRoller.py", line 16, in 
    counter[s] += 1
KeyError: 3
    from random import randint

```
while True:
    z = raw_input("How many sides should the dice(s) have?\n> ")
    i = 0
    x = raw_input("How many dices do you want?\n> ")
    dice = {}
    while i <= int(x):

        dice[i] = randint(1,int(z))
        i += 1

    counter = {}
    for p, s in dice.iteritems():
        counter[s] += 1

    print counter

    raw_input("Return to restart.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting each counter to the value `+1`:

```
counter[s] =+ 1
#           ^^^
```

You are not using `+=` there; Python sees that as:

```
counter[s] = (+1)
```

Swap the `+` and the `=`:

```
counter[s] += 1
```

This will raise an exception as the key `s` is not going to be present the first time; use `counter.get()` to get a default value in that case:

```
counter[s] = counter.get(s, 0) + 1
```

or use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) rather than a regular dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

counter = defaultdict(int)
for s in dice.itervalues():
    counter[s] =+ 1
```

or use a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do the counting:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(dice.itervalues())
```

Comment: I switched because: if i do += 1 i get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DiceRoller.py", line 16, in <module>
    counter[s] += 1
KeyError: 3                                      Ill fix the OP

Comment: @HåvardNygård: yes, because you can't add to values that are not yet in the dictionary. See my updates for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use xrange and just increment each count  as you go, using two dicts is unnecessary if you just want to count how many times each side is rolled:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from random import randint
z = int(raw_input("How many sides should the dice(s) have?\n> "))
x = int(raw_input("How many dices do you want?\n> "))

counts = defaultdict(int) # store dices sides as keys, counts as values

# loop in range of how many dice
for _ in xrange(x):
    counts[randint(1,z)] += 1 


for side,count in counts.iteritems():
    print("{} was rolled {} time(s)".format(side,count))
```

Output:

```
How many sides should the dice(s) have?
> 6
How many dices do you want?
> 10
1 was rolled 2 time(s)
2 was rolled 3 time(s)
3 was rolled 1 time(s)
4 was rolled 1 time(s)
5 was rolled 1 time(s)
6 was rolled 2 time(s)
```

If you want to include all dice sides in the output you can create the counts dict using xrange:

```
 counts = {k:0 for k in xrange(1, z+1)}
```

So the output will then be:

```
How many sides should the dice(s) have?
> 6
How many dices do you want?
> 10
1 was rolled 0 time(s)
2 was rolled 2 time(s)
3 was rolled 0 time(s)
4 was rolled 0 time(s)
5 was rolled 5 time(s)
6 was rolled 3 time(s)
```